# How do I make one column in my flex table occupy less width than the others?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create an HTML table using DIVs and the flex CSS property.  Roughly, all my rows look like

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='data-cell'>
      Col A
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='data-cell'>
      Col B
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='data-cell'>
      Col C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='data-cell'>
      <div class='img-wrapper'>
        <img src='images/delete.png' title='Delete' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Below is the CSS I'm using

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $lightGrey
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: col;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.header-row {
  color: $eclipse;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Right now the cells in each row take up 1/4th of the row width.  What I would like to change is make the col with the image only be the size of the image and have the remaining rows even split up the remaining space.  How do I do that using DIVs and flex?

Comment: I would check out `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns` if you're attempting a table style layout.

Comment: Use display:grid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one rendition of the `grid` method @Christopher Marshall and @dnaz mentioned.

In order to demonstrate each cell's size in the example, I used a wikipedia graphic and gave each cell a boarder.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) auto;
  gap: 15px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

section>div {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>Col A</div>
  <div>Col B</div>
  <div>Col C</div>
  <div class='img-wrapper'>
    <img width="50px" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Delete-button.svg' title='Delete' />
  </div>
</section>
```

Read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), but in short: `fr` = fraction of the free space of the grid container. The free space is calculated after any non-flexible items (in this case, the image).